# Is there a way to impute chi-square data?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, missing-data, multiple-imputation, mice

I've tried looking here, as well as the go-to book *Flexible Imputation of Missing Data*, but cannot seem to find any reliable information on how to simulate chi-square missingness (as well as imputing it with multiple imputation). I tried simulating some data like so. Note that while I have NA listed explicitly, I also tried with NA as a character value and it didn't change the outcome.

```
#### Load Library and Set Seed ####
library(mice)
library(miceadds)
set.seed(123)

#### Create Data ####
color <- c("blue","green","purple","red",
                 "orange","black","gray",NA)
choice <- c("yes","no",NA)

#### Sample ####
color.sample <- sample(color, size= 100, replace = T)
choice.sample <- sample(choice, size = 100, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(color.sample,choice.sample)
```

If you run `head(df)`, it will look something like this:

```
   color.sample choice.sample
1           red           yes
2           red            no
3         black          <NA>
4        orange           yes
5          gray          <NA>
6           red            no
7          blue            no
8        purple          <NA>
9        purple          <NA>
10         gray            no
11        black          <NA>
12       orange            no
13         blue           yes
14       purple          <NA>
15         blue            no
16        black            no
17       purple            no
18          red            no
19        black            no
20       orange          <NA>
```

Then all that's left is imputation...

```
#### Impute ####
imp <- mice(df)
```

Once I get to this last step, no matter how many ways I alter the factor data, I get this error:

```
Error in edit.setup(data, setup, ...) : 
  `mice` detected constant and/or collinear variables. No predictors were left after their removal.
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. I would think that if my data is randomly sampled, there should be no collinearity issues. What could be causing this and is there a solution? I looked in the categorical data section of Buuren's book, but the polyr, polyreg, pmm, and logreg methods all seem to not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mice` does not implicitly coerce character variables in your `data.frame` into categorical `factor` variables.  You can check the format of your variables using `str(df)`

This works:

```r
df <- data.frame(factor(color.sample), 
                 factor(choice.sample))

imp <- mice(df)
```

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm and simple to do. Thanks a bundle.